# Can I setup a notification whenever someone changes the access key from the IAM user in the AWS console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Can I setup a notification whenever someone changes the access key from the IAM user in the AWS console ?

I added AWS Config and have setup SNS subscription to send email to me.

[image]

But I haven't received any email notification when a new Access Key is generated .

TIA!

Comment: I believe those events will show up in CloudTrail and be available for you to trigger rules in EventBridge. I can't find an example of that particular event though. You'll probably need to look in CloudTrail for one of those events to see what it looks like, then create an EventBridge rule based on that.

Comment: Thanks Mark! I'll explore the EventBridge rule. I was thinking if I can do the same using AWS config and SNS

1. I've already setup AWS config to record all resources in my AWS account
2. Created a SNS topic and setup an email subscription to myself. 

Won't this work for IAM access key changes ?

Comment: Does AWS Config specifically track IAM keys as separate resources? I suppose that might work (although you said yourself in your question it doesn't appear to be working), but I don't think AWS Config would alert you in real-time as soon as something happens, like EventBridge would. In either case, sending the actual notification via SNS would be the same.